# Django Advanced tutorial: How to write reusable apps

Tags: python, django

According to [Django Advanced tutorial: How to write reusable apps](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/intro/reusable-apps/), "2. With luck, your Django project should now work correctly again. Run the server again to confirm this."

How to run the server? Having moved polls app from "mysite" to "django-polls" without manage.py and settings?

Please help with further instruction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`django-polls` is the new reusable app, but `mysite` is still your site; the idea is that you can extract the polls app but `mysite` will still work. You run the server there.